# How to access both the params and query string from a next.js Link in getServerSideProps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a component that links to a NextJS page in which I'm using getServerSideProps and need to access the params *and* the query string.

I really would like to have a 'clean' url such as 'domain.com/usersname/likes' without the '?userId=h337dhdh37dhdhd' on the end. Is it possible like this?

```
<Link href={`/${user?.username}/likes?userId=${id}`} as={`/${user?.username}/likes`}>
    ...
</Link>
```

In my getServerSideProps I'm using context as per the Next documentation:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const username = context.params.username;
    const userId = context.query.userId;
    ...
}
```

The params (username) are fine, but whatever I do the userId is always undefined. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, please?

EDIT: codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-bush-livm7 - based on Restricted Beam's answer below

Any help very much appreciated, Matt

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Are you sure the `id` variable is set when passing it to `/${user?.username}/likes?userId=${id}`?

Comment: Hi Julio, yes,as a test I set a const id = 'sampleId'; but it still came up undefined when I logged it

Comment: That's odd. Would you be able to provide a codesandbox (or similar) where one could reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sure, I've just edited the question to add a link

Comment: That codesandbox link doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to have a clean URL without the '?query=something' , you should try the **slug** and **dynamic routes** feature of nextjs. For using this feature:

- You need to change the file name to [...slug].js and all the
  different parameters in the link can be caught in an array.

So for "**domain/usersname/likes/userId**", your [...slug].js file will be in the root directory and to access its value you will use context like the following:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const username = context.params.slug[0];
    const userId = context.params.slug[2];
    ...
}
```

So, if your user visits the link:
**domain/user-XYZ/likes/12345abc**, the slug array would be like:

```
context.params.slug:["user-XYZ","likes","12345abc"]
```

Docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense, and it almost works.  I have refined my link to   <Link href={`/${user?.username}/userId=${myId}`} as={`/${user?.username}/likes`}>  and use context.params.slug[0] and context.params.slug[1]. However it seems to be using the 'as' part of the link for the params because when I log params.slug[1] it's giving me 'likes' - I understood that the 'as' part of the Link was the url visible to the user, while the href was used for the params. I can of course pass the params in the 'as' part of the Link, but this would then give me the ugly url.  Is my Link correct?

Comment: Just added a link to a codesandbox showing what's going on

Comment: No, 'as' is not just a 'visible url'. It is used for dynamic routing.
Your href will remain the same(file system path), whereas your 'as' will contain the dynamic link.
This is what i think should be your link:
<Link href="/[...slug]" as="/${user.username}/likes/${myId}">

Note: 'userId=${myId}' will not work as it is a query. It has to be the value itself.
Also, no you cannot get rid of the last part of the route as it will lead to loss of information(myID) from the URL.
Doc:https://nextjs.org/docs/tag/v9.5.2/api-reference/next/link#dynamic-routes